# Adverb for when a person has never questioned something they believe

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

What's an adverb to put behind "believe" when you're trying to communicate that a person has never questioned the thing they believe?

Example: Everything you've [ideal adverb] believed since birth

Comment: Is the adjective you seek approving or disapproving of belief without questioning?  Or possibly neutral?

Comment: Look up “unquestioned.” What among its synonyms does not work for you?

Comment: Your example shows [ideal adverb] in front of — not behind — *believed*. Where do you want your adverb?

Answer (score 9):

It could be:

**naively** - this is a simple, artless, almost naive word that means [ [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naively) ] "marked by unaffected simplicity" or even "deficient in worldly wisdom or informed judgment", i.e., dumb.

**unquestioningly** - this is a descriptive and self-explanatory word that you can't go wrong with in this situation, only it's a bit long and challenging to pronounce. Yet, its meaning is perfect! [ [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unquestioningly) ] "not questioning : not expressing or marked by doubt or hesitation".

**credulously** - I feel this is a perfect mix of naively and unquestioningly with a modicum of humiliating condescension: [ [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/credulously) ] "ready to believe especially on slight or uncertain evidence".

**artlessly** - I love this one. To me, it means dumb and happy at the same time or as [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/artlessly) has it: "sincerely simple".

Comment: You may add "uncritically" (non critical thinking does not require any proof of thought).

Answer (score 7):

I agree with "blindly", but I'd offer the second definition, which is better fitting:

> not thinking about or understanding what you are doing

From https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/blindly

Answer (score 2):

Without any information on desired connotation, I would simply go with **ever:**

> Everything you have ever believed since birth

OED has

> **1b.** Limited by a following adverb, preposition, or conjunction, as in *ever after(-ward), ever before, ever since, ever yet,* etc.: throughout all the time before or after a specified point in time.
>
> **5a.** At any time; (hence) on any occasion; in any circumstances.

While this doesn't necessarily exclude continuing to believe something after critically examining that belief, typically it indicates a continuing and probably unquestioned belief.

Comment: I don't think this matches the OP's description at all; "everything that you've ever believed" includes *any* belief you've held *at any point* -- things that you used to believe but no longer do, things that you came to believe only after a great deal of research, etc., etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

**automatically** https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/automatically "without thinking about it".

Beliefs that developed without any conscious action on the part of the believer.

Answer (score 0):

[Blindly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/blindly) is my answer with 30 characters

Cambridge gives:

> not able to see or not noticing what is around you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Jimmy, I added a source and definition for your answer.  It is up to you to justify it in more than 30 characters.